# import wxPython causes segmentation error

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to use wxPython, but I cannot import it

[image]

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

As you can see, it works in the python 2.7 version, but fails in 3.6

Are there any tools that can help me debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled wx.Python:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall wxPython
```

Reinstalled:

```
sudo pip3 install -U -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04 wxPython
```

Fixed!